# How can I left-align \name?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, resume

I am working on a resume using `\documentclass{res}` but I'd like it to left-align the name and address while using the `\name` and `\address` commands. I have tried using `\begin{tabular}...` and `\begin{ncolumn}{2}...` but this causes the name to not show up at all. Is there a way to do this?

My document has the following structure:

```
\documentclass{res} 

\newsectionwidth{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{10.2in}
\topmargin=-.5in
\oddsidemargin=-.5in

\begin{document}

%Name and address commands are placed here
\name{John Q. Doe}
\address{Address 1\\1111 Anywhere St\\Anytown, USA 00000\\(555) 555-1111}
\address{\empty}

\begin{resume}
% Rest of resume is here and rendering correctly
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

The example I followed had the following code, which placed one address on either side.

```
\address{Address 1\\1111 Anywhere St\\Anytown, USA 00000\\(555) 555-1111}
\address{Address 2\\9999 Anywhere St\\Anytown, USA 00000\\(555) 555-9999}
```

With a minor modification this did what I wanted

```
\address{Address 1\\1111 Anywhere St\\Anytown, USA 00000\\(555) 555-1111}
\address{\empty}
```

Thus I tried the following, but it still only placed the name in the center

```
\name{John Q. Doe}
\name{John Q. Doe} %Would be changed to \empty if it worked
```

This doesn't render the name at all

```
\begin{tabular}{p{3.5in}l}
\name{ John Q. Doe} 
1111 Anywhere St       & \empty\\
Anytown, USA 00000     & \empty\\
(555) 555-1111         & \empty
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: It's a good idea to give us a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that demonstrates your problem. That way we can copy and paste it, then have a tinker.

Comment: For professional and more modern-looking CV's, consider using the [`moderncv` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to place the name inside a box of width `\textwidth` and left-align the contents. This is achieved by using `\makebox[\textwidth][l]{<name>}`:

```
\name{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{John Q. Doe}}
```

[image]